# OptaPlanner multiple bin packing

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to figure out how to model this problem in OptaPlanner, or if it is even possible. For lack of a better term I'm calling it multiple bin packing.

The situation:
Incoming sales orders, each of which is an assortment of SKUs (specific items). Each type of assortment will have a minimum and maximum number of different SKUs in it.  The quantity of a SKU allocated to an assortment must be a multiple of N, assigned per assortment.  There are a limit number of SKU items that can be allocated to the assortment orders, and it is entirely possible that there will not be enough. The goals (for now) are to fill as many of the assortment orders as possible, within the given constraints, while minimizing the number of unused SKU items.

I don't think (but I could certainly be wrong) that it can be modeled as a normal bin packing problem. If the assortment order is the bin and the SKU items are the widgets then I'd need something to ensure that each bin was completely filled.

Similar situation if the quantity of available SKU items in the bin and the assortment orders are the widgets.

Comment: I am unsure what your question is. Do you want suggestions on a domain model or an estimation of whether it can be done (for the latter, yes, I think it can be done)? If you show me what you've already done I'm sure I can help, as I spent significant time on various variations on the bin packing problem with optaplanner.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear.  I'd like suggestions on the domain model. I tried making the assortment order the Planning Entity, also the SKU items, but in both cases quickly ran into the need to have an arbitrary number of planning variables for each.

I looked at the Nurse Rostering example, and thought the the EmployeeShift concept might work here, but I can't wrap my brain around how.

Comment: Update: I have a model that at least compiles and runs. I make the Planning Entity a SKUAllocation object, with the variable being quantity of that SKU assigned to the given order.  All possible SKUs are put on the order and the solver can assign null, 0 or some of them. 

It runs, but so far has not managed to produce a single properly filled order. I suspect that this is because I have the scoring such that a partially filled order is a hard negative score. 

Open to suggestions. Still working on it.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the CloudBalance example, which has 3 dimensions (cpu, ram, bandwidth) and x bins (= number of computers, for example 100) and y entities (= number of processes) to assign in those bins. As long as it's not 3D volume packing or 2D surface packing, that might be a good model to replicate for your problem.

Comment: @Mitch If you post at least a sketch of your solution along with a concrete question I'm sure I can help.

Comment: How do I go about posting a sketch?